# Single Sign On Implementation by making use of web service

Tags: jakarta-ee, oauth, single-sign-on, cas, josso

I am having an `REST` web service (for user authentication) and with the help of that I have to integrate `sso` for applications (which could be hosted on DIFFERENT DOMAIN).

I googled the stuff regarding `SSO` and found some solution in the form of `cas` & `josso`.

I also studied a bit about `SAML` and `OAUTH2` but didn't found a good example for it, Could someone please point me in the right direction how to implement `SSO`?

NOTE : The Implementation must make the use of web service to authenticate the user.

Comment: which application server? To narrow down, you need to search implementation details specific to your application server.

Comment: @SabirKhan Application Server : WebSphere

Comment: Its not a straightforward answer, you have to refer detailed guides and experts. Its a lengthy topic . During implementation, if you have specific questions, you can ask here.

Comment: @SabirKhan , Thanks I understand its a lengthy topic , i am just asking for some pointers and references to begin with

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make your Web Service receive the authentication token form a Security Token Service (STS) that is trusted by both domains for which you want to provide SSO. A common standard to broker authentication tokens is SAML; as far as I know, also josso uses SAML for the exchange of authentication information.

If you are looking for some code, I recommend the [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) samples, which contain an example for SSO authentication via a STS.

Comment: Thanks for the link , I dont have any control over that web service it just takes the username and password and returns a token

Comment: You will have to tell the STS to use your custom Authentication Service to identify users. Take a look at the examples....